# Return a variable from within a recursive Javascript function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, recursion, google-chrome-extension

I'm a Javascript novice writing a Chrome extension. I want to get an array of the bookmarks within a particular folder. I've copied some code which crawls the tree of folders and bookmarks, but when I modify it to return the contents of a folder it only crawls part of the tree.

It uses the Chrome bookmarks API. Each node has a title, URL and an array of child nodes.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/bookmarks.html#type-BookmarkTreeNode

```
function findFolder(bookmarkNodes, folderName) {
    for(var i=0;i<bookmarkNodes.length;i++) {
        console.log(bookmarkNodes[i].title, bookmarkNodes[i].url ?
            bookmarkNodes[i].url : "[Folder]");


        /* (A) this crawls the whole tree successfully
        if(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children) {
            traverseBookmarks(bookmarkTreeNodes[i].children);
        }
        */


        // (B) this stops at the first terminal branch
        if(bookmarkNodes[i].children) {
            if (bookmarkNodes[i].title == folderName) {
                return bookmarkNodes[i].children;
            }

            return findFolder(bookmarkNodes[i].children);
        } 

    }
}
```

When the commented code (A) is run, the console output shows all folders and bookmarks. When code B is run it only goes as far as the first branch with no children, and doesn't process sibling branches or the parent's siblings. The console shows the folder name for that branch, and all the bookmarks within it.

Scope issues seem to be a source of problems with recursive functions but I've tried things like making the function a variable (I don't really understand what that does though), and adding variables to store the bookmarks arrays within each iteration of the function, and it made no difference.

How do I get it to return the array of child bookmarks when the specified folder is found?

Comment: What is traverseBookmarks ?

Comment: you can wrap the whole thing in one more function, and use closure to set a local vairable in the wrapper that you return when findFolder is done.

Comment: Thanks guys. Matthew, sorry about that. I'd been hacking the code back and forth for ages and actually had the A and B parts in separate functions. I consolidated them here to hopefully make it simpler but missed the function name. Dandavis, I followed the Closure approach and it's working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I used a local variable outside the scope of the recursive function:

```
function findFolder(bookmarkNodes, folderName) {

    var bookmarks;

    function crawlFolders(bmn) {
        for(var i=0;i<bmn.length;i++) {
            console.log(bmn[i].title, bmn[i].url ? bmn[i].url : "[Folder]");

            if (bookmarks)
                return;

            if(bmn[i].children) {
                if (bmn[i].title == folderName) {
                    bookmarks = bmn[i].children;
                    return;
                } else {
                    crawlFolders(bmn[i].children);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    crawlFolders(bookmarkNodes);
    return bookmarks;
}
```